# ¿Cómo selecciono el mayor valor entre varias columnas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Tengo una tabla donde cada registro tiene columnas con monto de compras por mes. Es decir el `cliente 1` compro en `Mes1=500`, `Mes2=600`, `Mes3=400`.
Necesito seleccionar para cada cliente el mes con el mayor valor de compra.
Los datos a selecionar los tengo en columnas no filas.

Hasta ahora tengo esta consulta:

```
SELECT,[y], 
       (SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES ([Mayo2018]),([Abril2018]),([Marzo2018], 
                                   ([Febrero2018]) ,([Enero2018]) ,([Diciembre17])
       ) AS value(v)) as [MaxPuntaje] 
       FROM [x]
```

Comment: tienes algo hecho?

Comment: Tengo estoELECT,[y],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
   FROM (VALUES ([Mayo2018]),([Abril2018]),([Marzo2018],([Febrero2018])
      ,([Enero2018])
      ,([Diciembre17]))
       AS value(v)) as [MaxPuntaje]
FROM [x]  pero necesito saber el mes en que se dio el max puntaje.

Comment: @FlorenciaDiaz agrega toda esa información en tu pregunta como comenta Francisco, revisa [ask], saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Si cuentas con una versión de SQLServer igual o superior a 2008, puedes usar una sintaxis llamada [Table Value Constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para convertir los valores de las columnas en filas, y entonces podamos usar un `MAX()` común.

```
DECLARE @Ejemplo TABLE  (
    ID      INT,
    MES1    INT,
    MES2    INT,
    MES3    INT,
    MES4    INT,
    MES5    INT,
    MES6    INT
)

INSERT INTO @Ejemplo (ID, MES1, MES2, MES3, MES4, MES5, MES6)
    VALUES  (1, 10, 30, 12, 45, 33, 23), 
        (2, 30, 55, 17, 35, 23, 44)

SELECT  ID,
    MAXIMO,
    CASE    WHEN MAXIMO = MES1 THEN 'MES1'
            WHEN MAXIMO = MES2 THEN 'MES2'
            WHEN MAXIMO = MES3 THEN 'MES3'
            WHEN MAXIMO = MES4 THEN 'MES4'
            WHEN MAXIMO = MES5 THEN 'MES5'
            WHEN MAXIMO = MES6 THEN 'MES6'
    END AS  'MES'
    FROM (SELECT    ID, 
            MES1,
            MES2,
            MES3,
            MES4,
            MES5,
            MES6,
            (SELECT MAX(MONTO) 
                FROM (VALUES (MES1), (MES2), (MES3), 
                                 (MES4), (MES5), (MES6)) AS ALIAS_TABLA(MONTO)
            ) AS 'MAXIMO'
            FROM @Ejemplo
    ) T
```

Salida:

```
╔══════╦════════╦══════╗
║ ID   ║ MAXIMO ║ MES  ║
╠══════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 1,00 ║ 45,00  ║ MES4 ║
╠══════╬════════╬══════╣
║ 2,00 ║ 55,00  ║ MES2 ║
╚══════╩════════╩══════╝
```

Comment: Una consulta: como puedo hacer que me devuelva el nombre de esa columna, es decir, para el caso 1 me diga Mes5. Por necesito saber en qué mes se dio el max. Gracias

Comment: @FlorenciaDiaz deberías hacer un `CASE` y comparara cada columna con el valor máximo obtenido y retornar el nombre del mes. Saludos.

Comment: @FlorenciaDiaz, Verifica mi última edición. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podes definir una funcion para obtener el maximo, en este caso tomare prestada una de otra [pregunta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124417/is-there-a-max-function-in-sql-server-that-takes-two-values-like-math-max-in-ne)

```
create function dbo.InlineMax(@val1 int, @val2 int)
returns int
as
begin
  if @val1 > @val2
    return @val1
  return isnull(@val2,@val1)
end
```

Y luego utilizarla anidada en tu consulta select:

```
SELECT id_cliente,  dbo.InlineMax( mes1,  dbo.InlineMax( mes2, mes3 ) )
  FROM tabla;
```

Comment: Va a la funcion par cada tupla o envia un rowtype de n registros a la funcion?

Comment: La funcion es llamada por cada una de las columnas, supongo que se puede armar una funcion mas sofisticada que pregunte por cuantas columnas tiene la tabla y entonces vaya iterando por cada una, pero no se si sería realmente mas performante. Me pareció mas sencillo asi que armando un case, pero es igualmente valido.

Comment: cuando te llegan 100 registros, quieres decir que el motor va a la funcion 200 veces antes de mostrar el set de resultados?

Comment: La fujncion sera llamada n-1 veces por cada registro( una por cada campo que quieras saber cual es el maximo ).si tiene 100 registros y quieres comparar entre 3 campos entonces se llamara 2 veces en cada registro, serian 200 veces, pero ejecutaria unicamente 200 comparaciones( n-1 por registro). Mientras que con el CASE estarias realizando n-1 * n comparaciones, que serian 600

Comment: Si, pero llevate las 2 formas que proponemos y revisas el plan de ejecucion, podras notar los pasos extras que hace el motor al ir a una funcion de valores scalar. Creo que por rendimiento, basta con el case.

Comment: Contra eso no puedo argumentar

Comment: Muchas gracias @sacha, me funciona con estas 3. Lo voy a probar con las 24 columnas que tengo que comparar.

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Mes1 > Mes2 AND Mes1 > Mes3 THEN Mes1
    WHEN Mes2 > Mes1 AND Mes2 > Mes3 THEN Mes2
    WHEN Mes3 > Mes1 AND Mes3 > Mes2 THEN Mes3
END AS MaxMes
```

Un escenario que debes contemplar es cuando todos los montos sean iguales en los 3 meses, cual escoges?

Espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

No entendí a que te refieres cuando dices:

> Los datos a seleccionar los tengo en columnas no filas.

De todas maneras tengo una posible solución, siguiendo el ejemplo de este [artículo](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4067/find-max-value-from-multiple-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/).

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TABLETEMP') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #TABLETEMP

CREATE TABLE #TABLETEMP
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    CLIENTE NVARCHAR(40),
    MES1 INT,
    MES2 INT,
    MES3 INT

)

INSERT INTO #TABLETEMP(CLIENTE, MES1, MES2, MES3 )
VALUES('Jose', '500','600', '400'),
      ('Maria', '300','800', '200'),
      ('Petra', '500','100', '600')

SELECT
    *,
    (SELECT MAX(SELECCION) FROM (VALUES (MES1),(MES2),(MES3)) 
    AS MES(SELECCION)) AS SELECCION
FROM #TABLETEMP

DROP TABLE #TABLETEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

la función que podeis utilizar es GREATEST(columna1, columna2, columna3..)

https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/greatest.php

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/377180)